# Replace results of API fetch in browser window with results of a new call (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, str-replace

I have three similar functions that call JSON data from an API using HTML buttons, and change it to a string using stringify. The results display in a div, and each new call adds to the current browser page, making it longer. I would like to have each new call replace any previous data displayed in the page.

If I understand correctly, I can't use ReplaceChild once the JSON is stringified. I have tried using string.replace(), but perhaps I am using it incorrectly.

Here is the working code I'm trying to build on:

```
<body>
<button onclick="awardees()">View NDNP Awardees</button>
<button onclick="ocrFeed()">View Recently-Added OCR'd Pages</button>
<button onclick="batches()">View Available Batches</button>

<script>
function awardees(){
    fetch('https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/awardees.json')  
.then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                var string = JSON.stringify(myJson);
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += "<br/>"+string;
            });
}

function ocrFeed(){
fetch('https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/ocr.json')  
.then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                var string = JSON.stringify(myJson);
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += "<br/>"+string;
            });
}

function batches(){
    fetch('https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/batches.json')  
.then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                var string = JSON.stringify(myJson);
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += "<br/>"+string;
            });
}
</script>

<div id ="ticket">
<span id="results"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where would I need to add additional lines, and what method do you think would be best?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should only replace
`document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += "<br/>"+string;` by `document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "<br/>"+string;` and you will replace the div content with new string instead of adding it to the existent one.